# Javascript file has reference, but returns an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a pretty straightforward code and I don't understand what it's not working.

I want to reference app.js from within index.html. In the  part, I have a reference to it (if I press Ctrl + click it sends me to the right file), but when i run it in browser, I have the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Due to this, I also get the failed to load module from Angular, since it's not finding it.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module userApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'userApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

```
angular.module('userApp', [
    'app.routes',
    'authService',
    'mainCtrl',
    'userCtrl',
    'userService',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngRoute'
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User CRM</title>
    <base href="/">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.1/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-app="userApp" data-ng-controller="mainController as main">
</body>
</html>
```

The folder placement is like this

```
public/
----------
 - index.html
 - app.js
 - other_stuff
```

If I take the code from app.js and write it within `<script></script>` like this it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('userApp', [
        'app.routes',
        'authService',
        'mainCtrl',
        'userCtrl',
        'userService',
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngRoute'
    ]);
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Then inclusion of the script file is out of the application. Either you add that file to the bottom of the body or use `angular.bootstrap()`.

Comment: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_bootstrap.asp)

This, however, works flawless. 

What do you mean: use angular.bootstrap() ?

Comment: `angular.bootstrap()` you don't have to rely on the `ngapp` directive, you can create your module and just bootstrap it. you can see in the answer below or go through the ngdocs.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `angular.bootstrap()` there is no dependency with `ng-app` directive:

```
<body data-ng-controller="mainController as main">
</body>
```

now in the script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('userApp', [
        'app.routes',
        'authService',
        'mainCtrl',
        'userCtrl',
        'userService',
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngRoute'
    ]);

    angular.bootstrap(document, ['userApp']);
</script>
```

---

The issue seems to be with the usage of `<base href="/">` and you can learn about [`nobase` here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase).

Comment: It sill gives the same error. The angular tutorial says it doesn't matter where I place the <script></script>, since the data-ng-app will look after it when the document is loaded.

Comment: Thanks! The angular.bootstrap() got rid of the **module not found error**. But the **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <** from the **<script></script>** still remains.  I thought the module not found error was because of that but it seems I was wrong.

Comment: @AlexFlorin just saw the problem. that was due to `<base href="/">`. remove it to work. the module issue.

Comment: the module issue dissapeared after i replace **data-ng-app** with **angular.bootstrap(document, ['userApp']);**.  The one left now is **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <** from the **<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>**

Comment: What do you have in the script? Look if you have this `<` or this might be the issue with some async call to specific service that could be a error page.

Comment: The entire content of app.js is posted in my question, plus the angular.bootstrap which you suggested. Even if I comment everything in it, it still gives the same error.